# Tcl - Selenium WebDriver: Finding div element by contained text?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, tcl, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any tcl equivalent for:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Lookup Network Elements')]")?
```

I am trying to run something like:

```
set networkButton [$window element by_xpath "//*\[@class=\"frost-button\"\]//div\[contains(\"Network\")\]"]
```

But it gives me error

```
::invalidSelectorError10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your contains() is wrong, it is not looking for text() element. You need to write something like:

```
set networkButton [$window element by_xpath "//*\[@class=\"frost-button\"\]//div\[contains(text(), \"Network\")\]"]
```

or

```
set networkButton [$window element by_xpath "//*\[@class=\"frost-button\"\]//div\[text()\[contains(., \"Network\")\]\]"]
```

Comment: In this case, I strongly recommend `{//*[@class="frost-button"]//div[contains(text(), "Network")]}` or `{//*[@class="frost-button"]//div[text()[contains(., "Network")]]}`. There's no point in submitting to excessive escaping the way double quotes force you to unless you need to substitute some variable or something. If you *do* need double quotes, use single quotes for internal quoting and remember that you don't need to escape matched right brackets.